# What is the difference between Proof of Elapsed Time (PoET) and Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance (PBFT) algorithm?

Tags: consensus, blockchain

I am interested in these two consensus algorithms in the blockchain: **PoET and PBFT.** 
I saw this question about [PBFT algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80882/what-is-the-algorithm-for-blockchains-byzantine-fault-tolerance).

But, my questions are: **what is the difference between PBFT and PoET algorithm? Are they the same? If no, when to consider using PoET or PBFT algorithm?**

Thank you.